# reading an image file into a char array

Tags: c, arrays, image, file-io

I am trying to read a bunch of files into a char array,
I have the following code

```
FILE* file = fopen("...","rb");
//some error checking stuff
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long len=ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);           
char* content=(char *)malloc(len+1);
memset(content,0,len+1);
fread(content, len, 1, file);
```

I tested this with a text file, and that seems to work. I get the contents of the file in my array and all is good. but if this code runs with an image file (I tested pngs and jpegs), this only seems to read the first few bytes of the file. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: How are you verifying how many bytes are read?

Comment: Did you try doing a printf to decide that only first few bytes are shown?

Comment: Actually this code is running in a webserver and I get a error in the browser if I request for an image.
I did try a printf, but of course there is the possiblity that there were some unprintable characters. When I print out the contents on my array after reading a png image I get some 5-6 visible characters and among them are the letters "PNG". So I'm guessing this is a header of some kind.

Comment: @Niraj is this a CGI application? If so, you must send correct MIME type in the header at the begginning of the data output; `Content-type:image/png` in case of png data.

Comment: And how are you sending your bytes back to the browser? `fprintf` or `fwrite`? And there's no need to `memset` if you're just going to fill your buffer and the cast on `malloc` is unnecessary. Furthermore, you don't need a nul-terminator on `char*` (which really should be `unsigned char *`) used as a byte buffer, that's only needed for strings. And why not use `stat` or `fstat` rather than seeking around to find out how big something is?

Comment: I have that working. I have a switch case that checks the extension and adds the appropriate mime type. That seems to be working, in the sense that I printed it out to check I have the right mime type before sending it.

Comment: the memset was because this code is in a loop and some html from previous requests seemed to remain in the buffer, so I just added that to wipe those out. I'll check if fstat makes a difference.
About sending it to the browser, I have an helper function that creates a http response and I use send to deliver it to the client. That seems to work for non-image types. I tested both html and css files and those were rendered by the browser

Comment: both the fseek method and fstat give me the same filesize of 453965bytes, which corresponds to the size of the file. So I don't think there is an error there. thought fstat is much cleaner to look at.
somehow I still feel fread doesn't read as many bytes that I get as the filesize..

Comment: @mu `fseek()` is just fine and it is standard ANSI C while `fstat` or `stat` are not. @Niraj `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);` can be replaced with `rewind(file);` which is perhaps a bit more verbose and more clear.

Comment: oh ok. this is going to sound so stupid. I wasted the last 4 hours of my life thinking I wasn't reading the entire image, turns out it was working right all this while. I had my last parameter to send (the one that specifies number of bytes) to the strlen() of my buffer rather than the file size. so I was reading the whole image and only sending the first whatever-until-theres-a-\0 bytes to the browser.

Comment: @Athabaska: Fair enough. I tend to mentally mash POSIX and Std-C into one mental pile even though it isn't, in general, correct. I'd agree that `rewind` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [definintion of fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/), then it's not possible that your fread returns only the first few bytes since you put len into the size field and pass a count of 1. This means that fread will either return 1 on successfully reading len bytes, or it will fail having read no bytes. If you swap the parameters around then fread will read as many bytes as it can and will return how many bytes it actually read (should be len on success).

Also note that doing a memset 0 and then freading is inefficient, unless you demand that the array is zeroed on failure (error case should mean you don't have to). A better approach to adding the null terminator (as you do for normal files) would be:

```
content[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: yes, fread does read the whole thing. as noted in the comments, i made an error in the parameters to the socket send function. So although fread was giving me everything, I was sending only the first few bytes.